# Why can't I set a variable on my custom class?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm creating my first iOS app in Swift, and I'm stuck on a basic thing. I want to create a custom class and set a variable. I keep seeing the error "Value of type [Item] has no member [name].

This is my custom class:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import CoreData

class Item:NSManagedObject {

    var name:String?

    convenience init(name: String?, insertIntoManagedObjectContext context: NSManagedObjectContext!) {
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("ItemEntity", inManagedObjectContext: context)!
        self.init(entity: entity, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
    }
}
```

And this is my code that tries to use it:

```
func editItem(id:Int, category:String, brand:String, name:String, colour:String, purchasePrice:String, purchaseDate:String, expiryDate:String) -> Int {

    // vars
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("ItemEntity", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
    let item = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
    var listItem = [Item]()
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "ItemEntity")

    // fetch the item from the core data with the same ID
    do{
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id == %@", String(id))
        fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
        fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1
        let results = try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
        listItem = results as! [Item]
    }
    catch {
        let fetchError = error as NSError
        print (fetchError)
    }

    // edit the item
    listItem.name = "text"  // !! THIS IS THE LINE WHICH DISPLAYS THE ERROR

    // save the item
        do {
            try managedContext.save()
        }
        catch {
            let saveError = error as NSError
            print (saveError)
        }

}
```

Really appreciate your help, this one seems so basic but a lot of googling hasn't helped me figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*listItem* is an array of **Item**, so if you want to change the name of one thing in this list you should specify the index you wanna change, like

```
listItem[0].name = "text"
```

Answer (score 0):

Put spaces around the colon. Syntax if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem code is here:

```
let item = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext) as! Item
```

By default, the item type is `NSManagedObject`, so `listItem` have no  member `[name]`. You need to cast down it to Item Object.